# Django: How do i store a geo point in database

Tags: django, geocoding

Needed correct datatype for geo points.

I will get and display it with google map API so format like

- 42.761819,11.104863
- 41.508577,-101.953125

Usecase:

- user click on map
- django save this point with additional data
- on next visiting django display this points on map

So, no distances beetween points and etc hacks.

DB: postgres 8

Django: 1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [django documentation about DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield):

> #### DecimalField.max_digits
>
> The maximum number of digits allowed in the
>   number. Note that this number must be greater than or equal to
>   decimal_places.
>
> #### DecimalField.decimal_places
>
> The number of decimal places to store with
>   the number.

which is refering to the [Python Decimal](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal)

To make good choice about accurate data type and precission you should consider:

1. what is minimum possible value (latitude can be from 0 (down)up to (-)90 degrees)  _ _.
2. what is maximum possible value (longitude can range from 0 (down)up to (-)180 degrees) _ _ _.
3. what is accuracy (decimal_places), you wish. Pleas notice that it has impact on zoom level on Google Maps.

By the way, for better understanding, it is good to know how the calculation is done (Python code):

```
def deg_to_dms(deg):
    d = int(deg)
    md = abs(deg - d) * 60
    m = int(md)
    sd = (md - m) * 60
    return [d, m, sd]

def decimal(deg,min,sec): 
    if deg < 0:
       dec= -1.0 * deg + 1.0 * min/60.0 + 1.0 * sec/3600.0
       return -1.0 * dec
    else:
        dec=1.0 * deg + 1.0 * min/60.0 + 1.0 * sec/3600.0;

    return dec
```

Answer (score 11):

Check out GeoDjango and see if it helps you. If your stack is configured to run GeoDjango, you can do this.

Your models will looks like this

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
class LocationPoint(models.Model):
    point = models.PointField(srid=4326,dim=3)
    accuracy = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```

To save the point to the database all you will have to do is

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
point = Point(x=12.734534, y=77.2342, z=0, srid=4326)

location = LocationPoint()
location.point = point
location.save()
```

GeoDjango gives you extended abilities to do geospatial queries which you might be interested in the near future, like finding the distance between points, finding the nearest locations around a point etc.

Here's the link to [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/)

Comment: way to go if you dont want " and etc hacks." :-9

Comment: Does the Point have lon lat order? (lon x and lat y)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're going to be storing a latitude and a longitude. I would go with a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#decimalfield) for this, and store each number separately.

Answer (score 1):

I use longitude and latitude in my django setup.

My model includes:

```
long_position   = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
lat_position   = models.DecimalField (max_digits=8, decimal_places=3)
```

For more precision you may want the decimal_places to be more.

When you want to display it in the Google Map API method you would reference your model and write a python code to output like this:

```
output = some_long_position + "," + some_lati_position
```

Comment: This isn't right. Latitude and longitude numbers will never, respectively, contain more than 2 and 3 digits before the decimal (this example allows 5). This example also only allows 3 digits behind the decimal, meaning that values stored will only be [accurate to about 110 meters](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674), which might be OK, if you're guiding an ICBM with a megaton yield warhead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this in model

```
latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7,null=True,blank=True)
longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7,null=True,blank=True)
```